# Stack Overflow chat asks me to log in, but I am already logged in

Tags: discussion, support, chat, login, accounts

I have logged in to Stack Overflow. Now I want to go to a chat room for chatting. But the chat room shows me the following message:

> You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information.

How can I avoid this message and log in to a chat group?

Comment: Did you click that [logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackoverflow.com%2frooms%2f11%2fphp) link in that message?

Comment: Yes . But same message is coming : You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information.

Comment: Oh, could it be that an account merge took place? Because I assume [this is you](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5617522/sagor-ahmed) but the parent user no longer exists. This needs a moderator or dev to fix.

Comment: @SagorAhmed try now - it should work.

Comment: Thanks @JonClements . I am grateful to you .

Comment: @JonClements, I'm having this same issue. Please help. I've never been able to use chat yet.