# Stack Overflow chat asks me to log in, but I am already logged in, still

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, login, accounts

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/244193/mikeumus

Duplicate of [Stack Overflow chat asks me to log in, but I am already logged in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334761/stack-overflow-chat-asks-me-to-log-in-but-i-am-already-logged-in#comment729892_334761)

but I can't find where else to get help for this.

Comment: account merge went belly up I guess. A moderator need to push buttons to change the associated account, otherwise a dev needs to do magic.

Comment: Thanks rene. I'm 
Calling @JonClements  or someone... help..

Comment: @Mikeumus try joining chat now?